# How should I say "I will update on Next Tuesday"

Tags: prepositions

Should I say:

> I will update you by next Tuesday

or

> I will update you on next Tuesday

It's a bit confusing.

Comment: What is wrong with what you have?

Comment: "by next Tuesday" means you can provide the update anytime from now until tuesday. "I will update you next Tuesday" implies it's acutally happening on Tuesday.

Comment: We would never say "*on* next Tuesday" - it could be "next Tuesday" or "on Tuesday" - but not both together.

Answer (score 5):

I will update you by next Tuesday implies that it may happen before then

If you were to give an update on Tuesday you'd probably say:

"On Tuesday I will update you"